# css3 running header not working

Tags: html, css, pdf

I cannot seem to get running headers to work. Below is the css I have on my page:

```
@page { 
    size: letter;
    margin: 0.5in;
    @top-center {
        content: element(header)   
    }
}

#mainTitle {
    position: running(header);
}
```

When I go to print to PDF, in the preview I see my mainTitle where it is in my markup on the first page, but does not appear on subsequent pages. What am I doing wrong?

Browser: Chrome, OS: OSX

Comment: I've had problems with print previews not being accurate before. Is the actual printout wrong too?

Comment: When I Cmd+p in Chrome, Chrome's special print dialog shows up. If I choose to save as PDF, then open that saved PDF, it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently the version of OSX I am running (10.8.4) doesn't support CSS3's GCPM in the native "Save to PDF" action. When I used a PDF converter that does support it (Prince XML), it worked just fine.